# CSS do not inherit, but use default

Tags: css, class, inheritance, styles

Is there a general approach to avoid a property to be not inherited in CSS.

Example:

```
body {color:blue; }
a:link {color:red; }
a.special:link {something;foo;bar;}
```

Using `<a href="some" class="special">thing</a>` the link's font color gets red as of `a:link`, but I would like it to be blue like at body.

Of course I could say rewriting it to

```
a.special:link {color:blue; something;foo;bar;}
```

But imagine there are many properties in body I want to inherit and not from a:link.

Comment: Use the keyword `inherit` for `color`: http://jsfiddle.net/frWnj/6/

Comment: @KingKing If you post that as an answer, I would like to accept this as the best solution. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome, in fact it's too simple so that I did not want to add as an answer. It's interesting that the solution appears right in your question's title (the word `inherit`). I thought you would know about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's too simple that you can use the keyword `inherit` to specify some property to be inheritant from its parent. Note that not all properties can be inherited (inheritable). However `color` is one of inheritable properties, so you can do something like this:

```
a.special:link {
  color:inherit;
}
```

### [Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/frWnj/6/)